# Placing a Query Result in A String Variable

Tags: vba

Was wondering how can we put an SQL statement in a String Variable?

Example:
    Dim sqlQuery as String, qHolder as String

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT ID.table from table WHERE ID ='" userInputTextBox "'"
```

Whenever i do the above statement using either OpernRecordset() or RecordSource it gives me a bug. Can you give an example on how we do this, so we can use the value of sqlQuery for comparison for example
    if(sqlQuery = userInputTextBox)then
    MSgBox(" Match Found " )
    Else
    MsgBox("No Match Found")

Big Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the string concatenation operator (`&`).

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT ID.table from table WHERE ID ='" & userInputTextBox & "'"
```

Otherwise, it's a syntax error.

**UPDATE**

To get the value of `ID.table` into a string, use the [`Fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb257327%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of the [`Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177501%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
Dim s As String
' by index
s = MyRec.Fields(0)
' or by name
s = MyRec.Fields("ID.table")
```

Comment: Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Select ID From table WHERE ID ='" & userInputTextBox & "'"")

how can we set String=MyRec[Value] ?

Comment: instead of getting the value of fields. how can we assign
the result of the query statement  to variable s?

Comment: @dar3al: In your existing code, `MyRec` contains the result of the query statement. Why do you need to duplicate that in variable `s`? The purpose of the update was to demonstrate how to get the value of the selected field into a string (thus answering the question in your comment).

Comment: i understand that MyRec contains the result query, but when i tried to set stringHolder = MyRec, it gives me a bug. How can we place the value of a query from MyRec into a String variable temp? TO use in if statement if(temp = userInput) statement comparison?